# Quarto batch processing in python

Tags: python, quarto

Doing batch rendering with quarto using the following script From vscode

```py
import os
import glob
from pathlib import Path

PHASE = [0, 0.1, 0.2]
for f in PHASE:
    os.system(
        f"quarto render individual_reference_template_copy.qmd --output phase_{f}.html -P phase:{f} --to html --no-cache"
    )
```

**individual_reference_template_copy.qmd**

````
---
execute:
  echo: true
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
    theme: cosmo
jupyter: python3
---

```{python}
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```{python}
#| tags: [parameters]
phase = 0
```

```{python}
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi, 0.001)
y = np.sin(x+phase)
plt.scatter(x, y)
```
````

the output for the generated reports all show the same figure because the file

`individual_reference_template_files\figure-html\cell-5-output-2.png`

keeps getting overwritten.

**EDIT**
replacing the first post with minimal example

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of `individual_reference_template.qmd`? and also minimal examples of two `.mat` files would be helpful and easier to test the problem

Comment: I have edited the post and made a small reproduciple set to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to use [`embed-resources: true`](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-publishing.html#standalone-html) in the yaml section of the quarto document so that all the plots generated by quarto, css and javascript are bundled into a standalone HTML file.

````
---
execute:
  echo: true
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
    theme: cosmo
    embed-resources: true
jupyter: python3
---

```{python}
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```{python}
#| tags: [parameters]
phase = 0
```

```{python}
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi, 0.001)
y = np.sin(x+phase)
plt.scatter(x, y)
```
````

Then running the python script will create files with different plots for different parameters.

Comment: @kresten, did this answer of mine help you?!

Comment: Yes I accepted the answer. For my real example the rendering hangs while trying to access "cdnjs.cloudflare.com". :(